# React: Update array entry with button click

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have a code which updates the first entry in my array with a button click.

Does anyone have an idea what the solution could be?

Many thanks in advance,

Nicolas

I already tried the code attached.

```
class JobBuilder extends Component {
    state = {
        listings: {
            accepted:  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        }
    }
    acceptedHandler = () => {
                    const updatedCount = 1;
                    const updatedAccepted = {
                    ...this.state.listings.accepted        
                    }
                    updatedAccepted[1] = updatedCount;
                } 

    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <JobList 
                    listings={this.state.listings}
                    <button onClick={this.acceptedHandler}>Accept</button> 
            </Aux >
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: After this like   updatedAccepted[1] = updatedCount;   write  
 this.setState({listings:updatedAccepted})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Comment: Thanks a lot @imk for your answer. Would that not update all elements within listings instead of just the accepted array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator for arrays is []

`updatedAccepted[1]` will update the second entry instead of the first one.

Have a look at below code :

```
 acceptedHandler = () => {
    const updatedCount = 1;
    const clonedListing = {...this.state.listings};
    const updatedAccepted = [...clonedListing.accepted]
    updatedAccepted[0] = updatedCount;

    this.setState({
      listings: {
        ...clonedListing,
        accepted: updatedAccepted
      }
    });
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b3jrzc)

Comment: Thanks so much - this is the solution. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is it possible that this code deletes all other states in listings as well? It correctly updates my listings -> accepted, but seems to delete the other states in listings too.

Comment: i've updated the code and the stackblitz for this case, can you check ?

Comment: Thanks alot again!